# Number guessing by python ,show indentation block error

Tags: python, indentation

```
x=8
print " hello"
print " whats ur name "
myName= raw_input()
print"nice to meet you " + myName
print" i had guess a number between 1 & 10 \ can u guess"
myVariable= raw_input()
if myVariable>8 :
print"oops you are so agressive"
else:
print" you are getting closer"
if myVariable==8 :
print " good guess,lucky"
```

this throws "indentation block error", any idea why ?

Comment: Please use ctrl+k to format your `code`, and add a question so we know what you want.

Comment: Actually I m using phone and I m new here so I don't know how to type code here I use qpython

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you should have (I also replaced `8` with `x`)

```
x=8
print " hello"
print " whats ur name "
myName= raw_input()
print "nice to meet you " + myName
print "i had guess a number between 1 & 10 \ can u guess"
myVariable= raw_input()
if myVariable>x :
    print"oops you are so agressive"
elif myVariable==x :
    print " good guess,lucky"
else:
    print " you are getting closer"
```

`if`, `elif` and `else` should have the same indentation as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267119/indentation-of-if-else-block-in-python?rq=1), and you shouldn't mix white spaces and tabs.

Comment: Thanks for help raf

Comment: You're welcome. If it answers your question feel free to accept it as the answer and mark it as useful :)