# Python indentation not clear

Tags: python, indentation

Trying to understand how indentation works in Python.

```
var = 100                
if ( var == 100 ) :                      
    print ("Value of expression is 100")                 
    print ("Good bye!")
print("AM I out?")
```

Output:

```
Value of expression is 100
Good bye!
AM I out?
```

Isn't it only supposed to print the below output considering the indentation given for the if condition?

```
Value of expression is 100   
Good bye!
```

Why is the last statement also printed even though it has no indentation like the previous statements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Indentation of IF-ELSE block in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267119/indentation-of-if-else-block-in-python)

Comment: It is because it is a single if block. So it is going to check the condition, if it is true, it will execute the block and move on to the next statement which in your case, is the last print statement. Imagine it as a branch that is separated from the main continuity and later joins the flow.

Comment: "Why is the last statement also printed even though it has no indentation like the previous statements?" I can't understand the reasoning. "it has no indentation" is **exactly why** it runs; there is no condition on it running.

Comment: Alternately: the `var = 100` code happened, right? You aren't at all confused by that? But it wasn't inside the `if` block; so why should it run? The same thing applies to the last line.

Answer (score 3):

Python executes your program line by line,

```
var = 100                                 # First assign var = 100
if ( var == 100 ) :                       # Executed your if condition
    print ("Value of expression is 100")                 
    print ("Good bye!")
print("AM I out?")                        # Executed your last line
```

If you don't want to execute your last line when if is used,
keep `print("AM I out?")`  in else block.

```
if ( var == 100 ) :                       
        print ("Value of expression is 100")                 
        print ("Good bye!")
else:
        print("AM I out?")
```

**About Identation:**

It is used to know your program, that specific block statements belong to specific object(class, function, if-conditions, loops)

Answer (score 0):

The `if` block contains two indented print statements, which will be executed only if the condition is met. The `print('AM I out?')` statement which is on the same level as the `if`, is simply the statement after the block. It is unaffected by the condition. Had that statement been in an `else` block, it would not have been triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Everything on the same indent level is a *sequence*. It executes one after the other.

Everything that is indented is dependent on the line before the indent.

In your case, you have a sequence of three things: an assignment, then a conditional (which may or may not execute its own sequence of two things), then a print.

In order to make sure something *doesn't* execute as a part of the conditional, you need to introduce an `else` branch:

```
var = 100                
if var == 100:                  
    print ("Value of expression is 100")                 
    print ("Good bye!")
else:
    print("AM I out?")
```

Here you have a sequence of two things: one assignment and one conditional. The conditional has a sequence of two prints in the positive branch, and one print in the negative branch.