# Python expected an indented blockkkk

Tags: python

im relatively new to python and im not really sure how does the indentation for if else works.

Write a Python program that calculates the sum of all the numbers from x to y, where x and y are  numbers entered by the user.

```
print("This program prints the sum of range from x to y. ")
print("For example, if x is 10 and y is 50, the program will print the sum of numbers from 10 to 50. ")
x = int(input("Please enter the value of x: "))
y = int(input("Please enter the value of y: "))

if type(x) == int and type(y) == int:
 if x > 0 and y > 0:
    if y > x:
        sum_of_numbers = []
        for counter in range(x , y):
        sum_of_numbers.append(x)
        x += 1
        print("The sum of numbers from {} to {} is  {}".format(x,y,sum(sum_of_numbers)))

    else:
        print("You did not enter a value of y greater than x")
        print("Unable to continue.Program terminated.")
        exit()
 else:
    print("One or more inputs is not greater than zero")
    print("Unable to continue.Program terminated.")
    exit()       
else:
    print("One or more inputs is not numeric!")
    print("Unable to continue.Program terminated.")
    exit()
```

Comment: Btw, you don't need the line `if type(x) == int and type(y) == int`. In the lines before you do `x = int(...)` and `y = int(...)`. `x` and `y` will always be integers if you reach this part of the program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Indentation of IF-ELSE block in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267119/indentation-of-if-else-block-in-python)

Comment: You need to use the indentation in multiples of 4 (or 2) for every line. The second if seems to be indented only by two spaces, and the third if is by four spaces. Make it 4, then 8, and so on. Also, use all spaces, don't use tabs. Check your IDE for those settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
if type(x) == int and type(y) == int:
 if x > 0 and y > 0:                    # indented 1
    if y > x:                           # indented 3
        sum_of_numbers = []             # indented 4
```

You need to have *consistent* indentation, preferably four spaces for each indent, as per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Without that, the Python compiler (or you as well, really) can't tell how your code is meant to be structured.

Comment: Of course you _can_ use different levels of indentation, but you _should_  use 4 spaces.