# Why does else clause raise SyntaxError

Tags: python

I write my code and see this error:

```
from colorama import init
init()
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
print(Fore.RED + "Привет. Ты зашел в CrossoutHelper 0.1.1")
print(Fore.YELLOW + "1. Цены")
print(Fore.YELLOW + "2. Описание фракций")
question = input(Fore.YELLOW + "Что тебя интересует из выше перечисленного?")
if question == "Цены":
    print(Fore.WHITE + "На данный момент у нас имеются лишь цены редкого и обычного вооружения; редкой и обычной аппаратуры.")
    tip = input("Что тебя интересует?(Надо писать сразу редкость и тип): ")
    if tip == "Обычное вооружение":

        if tip == "Редкое вооружение":

            if tip == "Обычная аппаратура":

                if tip == "Редкая аппаратура":

                    else:
                        print("<неверный запрос>")
```

## Python test2.py

File "test2.py", line 19
    else
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: The else-clause should be indented the same as its corresponding if-statement.

Comment: Additionally, while it's legal to indent your if-statements like that, you certainly don't mean that for this code.  In order to reach the second if-statement you would have to first pass the first if-statement.  But if it passes the first it will not pass the second because they are comparing `tip` to different values.  If you want the if-statements to be independent they should be indented the same.

Comment: When I do it:  Python test2.py
  File "test2.py", line 19
    else
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: May I kindly suggest you first do [the official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Indentation of IF-ELSE block in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267119/indentation-of-if-else-block-in-python)

Comment: Please provide the entire error message.

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant to write something like:

```
if tip == "Обычное вооружение":
  pass # do something here
if tip == "Редкое вооружение":
  pass # do something here
elif tip == "Обычная аппаратура":
  pass # do something here
elif tip == "Редкая аппаратура":
  pass # do something here
else:
  print("<неверный запрос>")
```

The following does not make sense:

```
if tip == "A":
  if tip == "B":
    print("C")
```

`C` will never be printed because the variable `tip` cannot be equal to the string `A` and  `B` simultaneously.